# jQuery hover function doesn't work on ng-repeat angular objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I've created a jQuery hover function:

```
$('.deleteButton').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
},
function(){ 
    $(this).css('opacity', '.5');
});
```

It worked when I had the HTML element hard-coded into the index.html doc, but not when I import the element from a template.

Template below:

```
<div class="logBox">
<div class="dateAndLocation">
    <p>{{ info.date | date }}</p>
    <p style="margin-top:-.7em">{{ info.location }}</p>
</div>
<div class="routeNameBox">
    <p class="routeName">{{ info.routeName }}</p>
    <p class="gradeAndType">{{ info.grade }} | {{ info.type }}</p>
</div>
<div class="timeAndLevelBox">
    <div class="timeBox pull-left">
        <p class="timeText">{{ info.time }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pclBox pull-right">
        <p class="pclText">{{ info.challengeLevel }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="notesBox">
    <p class="notesText">{{ info.notes }}</p>
</div>

<div class="photoCircle" style="background-image:url({{ info.photo }})"></div>
</div>

<div class="deleteButton"><p>&#8212;</p></div>
```

index.html code:

```
<div class="container" style="min-width:1200px; margin:auto;" ng-repeat="climbLog in climbLogs">
    <climb-log info="climbLog"></climb-log>
<div>
```

It works fine and repeats as expected.. but when I hover over the delete button, it doesn't change it's opacity, as specified in the jQuery function (which had worked before I started using the template)

Comment: Don't use jQuery with angular, its not recommended and cause many issues. May be this link will give you some help https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave

Comment: Is jQuery comparable to Angular in terms of what it can accomplish? I'm just wondering if I should try to juggle my knowledge of both, or just invest fully in Angular. I'm thinking that jQuery is good for static websites, while Angular is good for dynamic websites/webapps... would you agree?

Comment: you can use jquery, after deeply know Angular well.

Comment: You _could_ say that (jQuery is good for static websites, while Angular is good for dynamic).  Even then it's only because angular is "heavy" and can do so much and would be a waste to include in a simple static site. But don't mix them within the same site like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is the fact that `$(...).hover(...)` will only collect the nodes that exist right now, and attach a `hover` handler on them. Thus, any future nodes that might eventually come to match the selector will not have the handler on them.

Using jQuery's `on` (with live selector functionality) solves this issue: `$('#placeWithDeleteButtons').on('hover', '.deleteButton', ...)`. This attaches the handler on the ancestor that catches the bubbled event, and checks if the triggering descendant matches the selector. Thus, since the handler is not on the trigger, you only need one handler to catch the event on any current or future matching nodes.

However, as comments indicate, you are better off using Angular's equivalents if you are working on an Angular project.

**EDIT:** Indeed, `hover` has to be broken down to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`:

```js
$('.logBox').on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".deleteButton", function(evt) {
  $(this).css('opacity', evt.type === 'mouseenter' ? 1 : 0.5);
});
```

```css
.deleteButton {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logBox">
  <button class="deleteButton">Foo</button>
</div>
```

However, if all you want to do is change opacity on hover, there is a way easier way to do it:

```css
.deleteButton {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.deleteButton:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="logBox">
  <button class="deleteButton">Foo</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But the jquery docs for `.hover` say it is just shorthand for `$( selector ).on( "mouseenter mouseleave", handlerInOut );`

Comment: But not for `$(ancestorSelector).on("mouseenter mouseleave", selector, handlerInOut)` (the live syntax), which is what I am talking about.

Comment: You are right, `hover` needs to be broken down to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. I'll put up an example in a bit.

Comment: looking at your (very thorough answer). I did try to change the opacity in CSS using the hover method.. but for some reason it did not work. Perhaps because the elements were loaded in using the angular app?

Comment: If you are setting opacity on hover from pure CSS, then it should work, Angular or no; but you need to make sure your selectors are correct.

Comment: The issue was that I hadn't removed the jQuery .hover bit. It was conflicting with CSS. Once I got rid of that, it worked. Thank you!